# 'CALayerInvalidGeometry', reason: 'CALayer bounds contains NaN' exception

Tags: ios, calayer

My app throws the following exception error after I press a `UIButton` which changes from a 'play' image to a 'pause' image. It doesn't always happen immediately, sometimes it happens when I pop to my root viewcontroller.

**Note:** It only happens in iOS 9.x, while in iOS 10.x works perfectly

Comment: You should either provide a detailed description of the problem and the solution or delete the question. As it is, this thread has no value to anyone else.

Comment: @DuncanC you can just read the answer. You do realize that by providing irrelevant code for this specific issue is of no use, or are you just trying to prove you point? Unless you wanted me to post the code of 5 viewcontrollers, protocols and storyboards.

Comment: Neither your question nor your answer provide enough information to mean anything to anybody but you. If you're not going to provide enough details so that other people can learn something from it it just clutters up the site and should be deleted. If you're using vector PDF images and that causes a crash, show some sample code on how you're installing PDF images and how that causes the crash.

Comment: @DuncanC So do you want me to post a video of me dragging and dropping a pdf in the assets catalogue?

Answer (score 0):

After hours of experimenting and searching, I discovered that the error was produced, because I was using vector pdf images in my project for that specific UIButton. As soon as I replaced them with their equivalent png files, the exception stopped occurring.

(Note: if someone finds out why this happens please post it)